# Per-Render Target blending on OpenGL 3.2

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am currently constrained to OpenGL 3.2 on my target platform and I don't have access to `glBlendFunci`. I can either use `glBlendFunc` or `glBlendFuncSeparate`. For example on OpenGL 4.4 I have the code below using `glBlendFunci`. How can I replace it on OpenGL 3.2 with the same result? Would it be better to create separate passes or it will hurt the performance?

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

// generate accum texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, accum);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, accum, 0);

// generate reveal texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, reveal);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, w, h, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, reveal, 0);


// blending
glBlendFunci(0, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glBlendFunci(1, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: It will certainly be better to do separate passes here, because the alternative is to get an incorrect result.

Comment: Can you add a separate passes example as an answer?

Comment: There's nothing to explain... rather than render the scene once to multiple framebuffers at the same time, you render it multiple times, to one framebuffer each time. There's nothing else to say about it.

Comment: Are you sure this won't work: `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an attempt to implement something like [McGuire and Bavoil's order-independent transparency approach (2015)](http://casual-effects.blogspot.com/2015/03/implemented-weighted-blended-order.html).

I ran into the same issue, trying to implement it in OpenGL 3.2, but not having glBlendFunci for per-render-target blending.

In my case, I got it working (at least, as a proof-of-concept) by the refactored approach in "Listing 4" of [their original paper](https://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/09/paper.pdf), which changes up the accum/reveal storage and uses `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` for both targets.